# Pydantic, sqlalchemy, fastapi, 'pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for'

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate and for my English, however. I started studying FastAPI and wanted to write my own online store. I filled the database with sqlalchemy and Pydantic, however, difficulties arose with obtaining data from fastapi, namely:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Cpu
response
  value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)
```

What does my code look like now:
cpu_model.py

```
class Cpus(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'CPUs'

    uuid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    brand = Column(String)
    model = Column(String, unique=True)
    image = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=True)

    specs = relationship('Cpus_Specs', back_populates='CPU_owner')
    prices = relationship('Cpus_prices', back_populates='CPU_owner')


class Cpus_Specs(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'CPU_Specs'

    uuid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    cpu_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('CPUs.uuid'))
    socket = Column(String)
    num_cores = Column(Integer)
    num_thr = Column(Integer)
    cache = Column(Integer)
    clock = Column(String)
    nm = Column(Integer)
    overclock = Column(Integer)
    tdp = Column(Integer)
    max_temp = Column(Integer)
    memory_type = Column(String)
    memory_clock = Column(String)
    memory_channels = Column(Integer)
    videocore = Column(Integer, default=0)
    model_videocore = Column(String, nullable=True)
    clock_videocore = Column(String, nullable=True)

    CPU_owner = relationship('Cpus', back_populates='specs')
```

cpu_schemas.py:

```
class CpuSpecsBase(BaseModel):
    socket: str
    num_cores: int
    num_thr: int
    cache: int
    clock: str
    nm: int
    overclock: int
    tdp: int
    max_temp: int
    memory_type: str
    memory_clock: str
    memory_channels: int
    videocore: int = 0
    model_videocore: str | None
    clock_videocore: str | None


class CpuSpecsCreate(CpuSpecsBase):
    pass


class CpuSpecs(CpuSpecsBase):
    uuid: int
    owner_id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class CpuBase(BaseModel):
    brand: str
    model: str
    images: str


class CpuCreate(CpuBase):
    pass


class Cpu(CpuBase):
    uuid: int
    specs: CpuSpecs

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

def from cpu_crud.py:

```
def get_cpus(db: Session, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100) -> list[Any]:
    return db.query(cpu_models.Cpus).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()
```

fastapi call crud:

```
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

@app.get('/cpu/', response_model=list[cpu_schemas.Cpu])
async def cpus(request: Request, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    Cpus = cpu_crud.get_cpus(db=db, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    gp.generate_category_page(query_result=Cpus, category='cpu')

    context = {'request': request}
    # return templates.TemplateResponse("cpu.html", context)
    return context # <--- here terminal call error,
```

Maybe I'm a fool, and that is normal, because in debug mode, I see that Cpus is a list with CPU objects, where all the fields of the class are inside, but it is confusing that specs is an InstrumentedList, in which one element is an object of the CpuSpecs class, with filled fields

Before

```
class Cpu(CpuBase):
    uuid: int
    specs: CpuSpecs

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

this class looked like in the documentation, i.e.:

```
class Cpu(CpuBase):
    uuid: int
    specs: list[CpuSpecs] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

also did `specs: InstrumentedList[CpuSpecs] = []`, but failed

What needs to be done to make the error disappear? call a database query from generatePage (this module generates html using Jinja2)?

Comment: Show us the request you're trying to send.

Comment: @Thiago As I can understand, db.query... executes the SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ... FROM table1 UNION SELECT ... FROM table 2), btw i just wanna take all datas from CPU and CPUSpecs, to transfer this data to the function and then generate an html page

Comment: I meant the HTTP request. What data you sent to `/cpu/`?

Comment: @ThiagoCurvelo amm, nothing? When I was writing a backend for academic practice at a university, we were told that sending something to a get-request is bad practice, so I just call /cpu/ wanting to see a list of CPUs

Comment: Why are you returning `{'request': request}`? You specified the response model to be a list of `Cpu` model objects. Shouldn't you be returning just `Cpus` instead? It seems as if you don't really understand, what a route handler function is even supposed to do. I suggest you go through the FastAPI Tutorial/Documentation.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg btw, i tryed to use ```response_model=list[cpu_schemas.Cpu]``` as it was written in the documentation, but it did not bring any success. In any case, I tried to do it now, and the error is still there. I'll figure it out then on my own